# What is the common UI practice if you want to display a series of dialogs?

Tags: android, modal-windows

In my case (see picture) I display a dialog which requires the user to select date and time. This happens through another dialog which appears above the first dialog. Is this fine for user experience?

Some other solutions come to my mind:

1. Don't show another dialog, replace the existing dialog content with the new dialog content. This way we are reusing a single dialog window, we just change its content.
2. Show the first dialog in normal screen, not dialog window.

What do you think?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with your option 2 and put the date & time on the main screen, and have a dialog to pick start & end time.  I don't see any need to use multiple sequenced dialogs.

Even better would be to use an inline picker that appears in the list when you tap the date, and disappears once you've selected a time. (take a look at the calendar app in iOS 7).

Comment: +1 Android seems to offer full screen dialogs http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#FullscreenDialog